# WPF buttons not responding

Tags: wpf, powershell, wpf-controls

I'm trying to use WPF to display a window for user to enter a password in my PowerShell script, the window works but buttons do not respond...

The main window (which also use WPF) works fine, I only have this strange behavior with this one.

XAML code :

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    WindowStyle="None"
    MinWidth="200" MaxWidth="400" Width="300"
    MinHeight="100" MaxHeight="120" Height="110"
    FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="13">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Name="Label" Grid.Row="0" Content="Enter vault master key:" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <PasswordBox Name="Input" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0.5" Margin="10,5,10,5" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Name="Ok" Content="Ok" Width="70" Height="20" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
            <Button Name="Exit" Content="Exit" Width="70" Height="20" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

PowerShell code :

```
[xml]$xaml = (Get-Content -Path $Files.Inp) 
$xamlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml

$UserInput = @{}
$UserInput.Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($xamlReader)
$Controls = [regex]::Matches((Get-Content $Files.Inp -Raw),'Name="(\w+)"')
$Controls.Groups  | Where-Object Name -eq 1 | ForEach-Object{ $UserInput.($_.Value) = $UserInput.Window.FindName($_.Value) }
$UserInput.Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

$UserInput.Ok.Add_Click({
   $UserInput.Input.Password
   $UserInput.Window.Close()
})
$UserInput.Exit.Add_Click({ $UserInput.Window.Close() })
```

When I run the script, the window display and I can write in the password box but both button (Ok/exit) do not work (nothing append when I click on). I checked controls name and method I use (Add_Click), all seems right...

Can you help me ?

Comment: I haven't integrated WPF with Powershell before, but you don't have an event handler attached to your buttons in the xaml. Your WPF app won't do anything without a click event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to move:

```
$UserInput.Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

to the bottom of your script

Comment: Damn, I'm stupid -_-'

Thanks ;)